# H2 DB CSVREAD command converting value to date before placing into VARCHAR

Tags: sql, import, h2, csv

I am attempting to load a tab delimited text file which contains a column of values which happen to look exactly like a date, but aren't. It appears that the CSVREAD command scans the row, converts the text value in the column to a java.Sql.Date, and then sees that the target column is a VARCHAR and executes toString() to obtain the value...which is exactly NOT what I need. I actually need the raw unconverted text with no date processing whatsoever.

So, is there some way to turn off "helpful date-like column conversion" in the CSVREAD command?

Here's the simplest case I can make to demonstrate the undesired behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE x
  (
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL
    value VARCHAR
  ) AS
  SELECT *  CSVREAD('C:\myfile.tab', null, 'UTF-8', chr(9))
;
```

The file contains three rows, a header and two records of values:

```
name\tvalue\n
x\t110313\n
y\t102911\n
```

Any assistance on how I can bypass the overhelpful part of CVSREAD would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Disregard! ARGH! Input file was invalid. Had "3/10/2013 0:00:00" present. Should have verified that first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(It seems you found this out yourself, but anyway):

For `CSVREAD`, all columns are strings. The `CSVREAD` function or the database do **not** try to convert values to a date, or in any other way try to detect the data type. The database only does what you ask it for, which is read the data as a string in your case.

If you do want to convert a column to a date, you need to do that explicitly, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE x(name VARCHAR NOT NULL, value TIMESTAMP) AS
SELECT * 
FROM CSVREAD('C:\myfile.tab', null, 'UTF-8', chr(9));
```

If non-default parsing is needed, you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE x(name VARCHAR NOT NULL, value TIMESTAMP) AS
SELECT "name", parsedatetime("value", "M/d/y") as v 
FROM CSVREAD('C:\myfile.tab', null, 'UTF-8', chr(9));
```

Comment: Ah! Tyvm! I had forgotten you could do the non-default parsing pathway. I really appreciate your elaborating.

Answer (score 2):

For people who don't have headers in there csv files the example could be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE x(name VARCHAR NOT NULL, value TIMESTAMP) AS
SELECT "0", parsedatetime("1", 'd-M-yyyy') as v 
FROM CSVREAD('C:\myfile.tab', '0|1', 'UTF-8', '|');
```

Beware of the single quotes around the date format. When I tried the example from Thomas it gave me an error using H2:

> Column "d-M-yyyy" not found; SQL statement:

My csv files:

```
firstdate|13-11-2013\n
seconddate|14-11-2013
```